# where to suggest ideas

Tags: ros, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I started developing stuff using ROS2 about a month ago. If I have an idea for a ROS package, where would be the appropriate place be to discuss it and garner support? I am thinking of making a higher-level API over rclpy that is more beginner friendly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404312/where-to-suggest-ideas/) by [Interpause](https://answers.ros.org/users/109666/interpause/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, you can open a discussion on [ROS Discourse](https://discourse.ros.org/). This will be the best way to gather attention about your package, and also to obtain feedback/input that might be helpful for you to continue improving it.

There is a category called [ROS Projects](https://discourse.ros.org/c/ros-projects/10), that you might particularly find interesting

---

Originally posted by [sampreets3](https://answers.ros.org/users/87884/sampreets3/) with karma: 230 on 2022-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2